# java 7 command usage issue

Tags: java, jvm, javaexe

I am getting:

> java version "1.7.0_55" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
>
> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)
>
> where options include:
>       -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
>       e.t.c

Can someone please tell me if you see some java options/arguments that don't belong in the java 7 command (options placed in new line for perspicuity):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java"  
-server  
-XX:+AggressiveOpts   
-showversion  
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m  
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  
-Xmx512m  
-Dcom.sun.jini.reggie.initialUnicastDiscoveryPort=4169  
-Dcom.gs.deploy=C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800/deploy  
-DagentId=  
-DgsaServiceID=  
-DenableDynamicLocators=  
-Xbootclasspath/p:"C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\xml\*"  
-cp ;"C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\";"C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\sigar\*;";"C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\boot\gs-boot.jar";  
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=36000000  
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=36000000  
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=""SOMEONE-PC""  
-Djava.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi=default  
-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=false  
-Dcom.gs.jini_lus.locators=null  
-Dcom.gs.jini_lus.groups=me  
-Dcom.gs.logging.debug=false  
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\gigaspaces-xap-premium-9.7.1-ga-b10800\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\/config/gs_logging.properties" 
com.gigaspaces.start.SystemBoot  
com.gigaspaces.start.services=\"GSA\"  
gsa.gsc 0 gsa.global.gsm 0 gsa.lus 1
```

Comment: Well what have you tried in terms of diagnosing this? I'd start by removing all of the `-D` options for simplicity, and then go one by one looking at the other options.

Comment: You are asking it to show the version. That is what it is doing, along with a usage message. Try removing -showversion

Comment: tried removing the -XX options the empty -D arguments (-Dsomething= ) -showversion (this doesn't prevent the execution - only prints the version along the way)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some issue with this part in the path:

```
\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\
```

changing those arguments made it possible to run the command in java 7.

Cheers!